# Setting link font with CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, hyperlink

I want to use the font 'Libre Baskerville' for my links.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Libre Baskerville";
}
```

How can I set the font?

Comment: Is Libre Baskerville available on the client?

Comment: Is this a Google font or an embed font. Did you reference the font at the top of your stylesheet? We need more information

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very commonly-preinstalled font. You may have to use a "@font-face" declaration so that people can download the font for use. (Could be wrong though! See if Internet Explorer shows it; IE will usually pull from the locally installed fonts)

Comment: Have you loaded the font already using `@font-face` or are you sure, all clients have it installed (e.g., on an intranet, ...)?

Comment: Are you importing the font or including the necessary font-face files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libre Baskerville is probably not available on the client by default, but you can load it through CSS. You can serve it from your own server, but it is probably more convenient to serve it from Google:

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Libre+Baskerville

There you can click to the configurator:

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Libre+Baskerville

You can select the styles and character sets you like. Choose wisely, and select the most minimal options you need. Fewer options mean smaller downloads (there is a gauge indicator on the page), and smaller downloads result in faster page loads.

When you're done, you'll get a line to include the font, like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

After that, you can use it as you did in your CSS:

```
font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
```